# If 'app-fixed-topbar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

If 'app-fixed-topbar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
I got this error.
suppose i include the "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" am not getting the  "app-fixed-topbar" it is not visible to me

Comment: Add the component class name to declarations array in your app.module.ts like `declarations: [FixedTopbarComponent]`

Answer (score 0):

Add declaration component in your module,

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [FixedTopbarComponent],
  imports: [ ....],
  ... 
  ...
})
export class YourModule { }
```

Comment: Already done.but am still getting the error. suppose am not using "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" i got that error suppose i used  that "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" am not geeting the header part but that html content seen in inspect,

Answer (score 0):

If your using the component within its module then you must add it in the declaration as shown,

```
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [FixedTopbarComponent],
      imports: [ ....],
      ... 
      ...
    })
    export class ModuleName{ }
```

If your using the component outside its module then add it in the declaration and also in the exports as shown,

```
        @NgModule({
          declarations: [FixedTopbarComponent],
          exports: [FixedTopbarComponent],
          imports: [ ....],
          ... 
          ...
        })
        export class ModuleName{ }
```

Comment: Already done.but am still getting the error. suppose am not using "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" i got that error suppose i used that "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" am not geeting the header part but that html content seen in inspec